# Windows QGIS PostGIS connection to Ubuntu PostgreSQL database

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, database

I have QGIS software in my Windows system and I want to make PostGIS connection to a database present in Ubuntu system, both are in same network(LAN). How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

There is a couple of ways to enter database connection parameters, one of them would be:

1. Open **Data Souce Manager**

[image]

2. Select **PostgreSQL** and click **New**

[image]

3. Enter your credentials:

[image]

4. Hit **Test Connection**. If everything is fine, a light blue log on top of the window indicates that the connection was successful:

[image]

Comment: Good answer. One thing for the poster to note as well, they need to make sure the PostgreSQL database is accepting outside connections. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18580066/how-to-allow-remote-access-to-postgresql-database